# Splitting up `h5` file and combining the pieces back

Tags: python, keras, hdf5, tf.keras, h5py

I have an `h5` file, which is basically model weights output by `keras`. For some storage requirements, I'd like to split up the large `h5` file into smaller pieces, and combine them back into a single file when needed. However, the way I do it seems to miss some "metadata" (not sure, maybe it's missing a lot more, but judging by the size of the combined file and the original file, it seems that I'm not missing much).

Here's my splitting script:

```py
prefix = "model_weights"
fname_src = "DiffusiveSizeFactorAI/model_weights.h5"
size_max = 90 * 1024**2  # maximum size allowed in bytes
is_file_open = False
dest_fnames = []
idx = 0

with h5py.File(fname_src, "r") as src:
    for group in src:
        fname = f"{prefix}_{idx}.h5"
        if not is_file_open:
            dest = h5py.File(fname, "w")
            dest_fnames.append(fname)
            is_file_open = True
        group_id = dest.require_group(group)
        src.copy(f"/{group}", group_id)
        size = os.path.getsize(fname)
        if size > size_max:
            dest.close()
            idx += 1
            is_file_open = False
    dest.close()
```

and here's the script that I use for combining back the pieces:

```py
fname_combined = f"{prefix}_combined.h5"

with h5py.File(fname_combined, "w") as combined:
    for fname in dest_fnames:
        with h5py.File(fname, "r") as src:
            for group in src:
                group_id = combined.require_group(group)
                src.copy(f"/{group}", group_id)
```

Just to add a little bit of context if it helps debugging my case, when I load the "combined" model weights, here's the error I'm getting:

```py
ValueError: Layer count mismatch when loading weights from file. Model expected 108 layers, found 0 saved layers.
```

**Note:** the size of the original file and the combined one are about the same (they differ by less than 0.5%), which is why I think that I might be missing some metadata.

Comment: HDF5 metadata is saved as attributes. They are copied when using the group copy method. However, you are creating the group with require_group, so they may not get copied. I think you can comment out that line, and your code will still work. You can compare both files with the h5dump utility from The HDF Group.

Comment: @kcw78 Thank you for the hint. Actually, the issue was that the attributes of the "root" level wasn't being copied, since I was iterating through the Groups within the "root" folder. The fix was as easy as running `dest.attrs.update(src.attrs)`. I'll update both the question and the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on an [answer](https://github.com/h5py/h5py/issues/2086) from `h5py` developers, there are two issues:

1. Every time an `h5` file is copied this way, a duplicate extra folder level will be added to the destination file. Let me explain:

Suppose in `src.h5`, I have the following structure: `/A/B/C`. In these two lines:

```py
group_id = dest.require_group(group)
src.copy(f"/{group}", group_id)
```

`group` is `/A`, and so, after copying, an extra `/A` will be added to `dest.h5`, which results in the following erroneous struction: `/A/A/B/C`. To fix that, one needs to explicitly pass `name="A"` as an argument to `copy`.

2. Metadata of the root level "/" is not being copied neither in the splitting nor in the combining script. To fix that, given that `h5` data structure is very similar to Python's `dict`, you just need to add:

```py
dest.attrs.update(src.attrs)
```

For personal use, I've written two helper functions, one that splits up a large `h5` file into smaller parts, each not exceeding a specified size (passed as argument by user), and another one that combines them back into a single `h5` file. In case you find it useful, it can be found on Github [here](https://github.com/PMEAL/sf-model-zoo/blob/main/h5tools.py).

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering if there is an alternative solution to your problem. I am assuming you want to deploy the model on an embedded system, which leads to memory restrictions. If that is the case, here are some alternatives:

1. Use [TensorFlow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide): claims that it significantly reduces the size of the model (haven't really tested this). It also improves other important aspects of ML deployment on the edge. In summary, you can make the size up to x5 times smaller.
2. Apply [Pruning](https://www.tensorflow.org/model_optimization/guide/pruning/pruning_with_keras): pruning gradually zeroes out model weights during the training process to achieve model sparsity. Sparse models are easier to compress, and thus the zeroes during inference can be skipped for latency improvements.